# Является ли литературным слово "шиза"?

Tags: лексика

Является ли литературным слово"шиза"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это слово ни в коем случае не является литературным, и если станет таковым, то не скоро.
Тем не менее, оно активно употребляется в повседневной речи, часто в шутку:

а в мастерской у папы карло
с утра какая-то шиза
в своём бревне он замечает
глаза

Иногда употребляется неологизм "демшиза́". Это грубоватое слово, каким называют демократических радикалов-фанатиков вульгарного толка. (Определение принадлежит С. А. Ковалёву.)

Comment: На будущее: переход на новую строку можно сделать, завершив строку двумя пробелами.

Comment: Спасибо! Буду использовать.

Answer (score 2):

Это неформальное сокращение от "*шизофрения*", характерное для *устной речи* (ср. "гимор" от "геморрой") или для переписки в интернет-форумах. Здесь имеет место *усечение основы* слова по образцам "инфа" (информация), "препод" (преподаватель), "прибалты", "фак" (факультет в речи студентов) и т. п.  (https://www.hse.ru/data/2014/01/17/1327304435/2kuvshinskaja.pdf)

Такого же порядка "литературности" распространяемое в последнее время телевидением упрощение "цифра" ("переход на цифру"), обозначающее *цифровую форму* чего-либо в речи неспециалистов (упрощение достигается заменой прилагательного с зависимыми словами коротким существительным).